# Sci-fi story with the premise that spacetime geometry is Riemannian

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi, physics, relativity

I'm trying to find a hard sci-fi story where one of the major premises was that the world has a Riemannian geometry (x^2+y^2+z^2 **+** t^2) instead of the real world's Minkowski geometry (x^2+y^2+z^2 **-** t^2). The effects of this on relativity and how it affected the world were very significant. Here's some of the effects that I remember:

- Stars, instead of looking like points of white light, looked like lines that were cross-sections of a rainbow
- It was impossible for two objects to collide with certain velocities unless a third object was also present
- It was possible to "turn around" your direction through time, just as it's possible to turn around the direction you're moving through space in the real world

I remember seeing this online several years ago, along with an out-of-character analysis of the setting that explained all of the above effects in detail. Does anyone know what this is and/or where I found it?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)?

Comment: @Loki it's indeed called Riemannian, not Euclidean.

Comment: @JosephSible Riemannian manifolds is the more general term, it contains both Minkowski and Euclidean metrics. Feel free to check Wikipedia.

Comment: @Loki I meant that now that it's been answered, I've confirmed that Riemannian is the major term the author uses to describe it, so even if Euclidean would be more correct from a technical perspective, Riemannian is much more helpful for anyone else who would search for this question.

Comment: @Rebel-Scum: Minkowski is *pseuso*-Riemannian.  Riemannian it is not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sounds like Greg Egan’s *[Orthogonal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_(series))* trilogy. There is considerable technical detail (more than 80,000 words, so enough for another novel) on [Egan’s website](http://www.gregegan.net/ORTHOGONAL/ORTHOGONAL.html).

> Orthogonal is a science fiction trilogy by Australian author Greg Egan
>   taking place in a universe where, rather than three dimensions of
>   space and one of time, there are four fundamentally identical
>   dimensions. While the characters in the novels always perceive
>   three of the dimensions as space and one as time, this classification
>   depends entirely on their state of motion, and the dimension that one
>   observer considers to be time can be seen as a purely spatial
>   dimension by another observer.
>
> Technically, the space-time of the universe portrayed in the novels
>   has a positive-definite Riemannian metric, rather than a
>   pseudo-Riemannian metric, which is the kind that describes our own
>   universe.

Comment: Note that Egan has also written the novel _Dichronauts_, set in a universe with two space dimensions and two time dimensions, a space-time signature of (+ + - -).

Comment: I find it hard to understand how the second law of thermodynamics would apply in such a universe. It's through burning away low-entropy states that time has an arrow in our universe. In a plain 4D block, there's no philosophical reason for anything living to exist. (I mean, sure, there's no (scientifically) identified-yet reason for the Big Bang to exist, either --nor, even if the Big Bang is just a local low-entropy fluctuation as I've seen mentioned as a possibility by Sean Carroll, for the wider fabric to exist-- but the low entropy initial state at least allows logical progressions.)

Comment: Note: I've checked out http://www.gregegan.net/ORTHOGONAL/05/Thermodynamics.html a bit but I'm still confused. Perhaps reading the books themselves would make it clearer.